# Not Getting Data into my Recycler View using Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

My RecyclerView is not displaying any data.

buynow.java

```
public class buynow extends AppCompatActivity {
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
DatabaseReference ProductRef;
private EditText searchField;
private Button search_btn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_buynow);

    ProductRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Products");

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    searchField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_field);
    search_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.search_button);

    search_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            firebaseUserSearch();
        }
    });
}

    private void firebaseUserSearch(){

    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Products> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Products>()
            .setQuery(ProductRef,Products.class).build();

    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Products, UsersViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new 
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Products, UsersViewHolder>(options) {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull UsersViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull 
    Products model) {

            holder.setDetails(model.getPname(), model.getPprice(), model.getPmrp(), 
    model.getPcondition(), model.getPimage());

        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public UsersViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            return null;
        }
    };

    recyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);

}

//View Holder Class

public class UsersViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    View mView;

    public UsersViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        mView = itemView;
    }

    public void setDetails(String phoneName, String phonePrice, String phoneMrp, String 
    phoneCondition, String phoneImage){

        TextView phone_name = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.product_name);
        TextView phone_price = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.product_price);
        TextView phone_mrp = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.product_mrp);
        TextView phone_condition = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.product_condition);
        ImageView phone_image = (ImageView)mView.findViewById(R.id.product_image);

        phone_name.setText(phoneName);
        phone_price.setText(phonePrice);
        phone_mrp.setText(phoneMrp);
        phone_condition.setText(phoneCondition);
        Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(phoneImage).into(phone_image);

    }
  }
}
```

Products.java

```
public class Products {
private String pname,pprice,pimage,pmrp,pcondition;

public Products(){
}

public Products(String pname, String pprice, String pimage, String pmrp, String pcondition) {
    this.pname = pname;
    this.pprice = pprice;
    this.pimage = pimage;
    this.pmrp = pmrp;
    this.pcondition = pcondition;
}

public String getPname() {
    return pname;
}

public void setPname(String pname) {
    this.pname = pname;
}

public String getPprice() {
    return pprice;
}

public void setPprice(String pprice) {
    this.pprice = pprice;
}

public String getPimage() {
    return pimage;
}

public void setPimage(String pimage) {
    this.pimage = pimage;
}

public String getPmrp() {
    return pmrp;
}

public void setPmrp(String pmrp) {
    this.pmrp = pmrp;
}

public String getPcondition() {
    return pcondition;
}

public void setPcondition(String pcondition) {
    this.pcondition = pcondition;
}
}

Layout for RecyclerView
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingLeft="10dp"
android:paddingRight="10dp"
android:paddingTop="5dp"
android:paddingBottom="5dp"
android:background="@color/primanrybg">

<RelativeLayout
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/buyphones_layout_bg">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/product_image"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:src="@drawable/rapid_pickup_foreground" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/product_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/product_image"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:paddingStart="16dp"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:text="iPhone 6s Space Grey (64GB)"/>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/condition"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/product_image"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/search_frame"
        android:layout_below="@id/product_name"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        android:padding="2dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/yes_no_bg"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:paddingStart="4dp"
            android:padding="1dp"
            android:paddingEnd="4dp"
            android:text="Condition:" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/product_condition"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:padding="1dp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:text="Like New" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/product_price"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/condition"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/product_image"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:paddingStart="16dp"
        android:text="9,9999"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/product_mrp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/product_price"
        android:layout_below="@id/condition"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:text="24000"
        android:textColor="@color/grey"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"/>
```

I am not getting data into my RecyclerView. It is just not showing anything no error nothing. Any help is very appreciated.
I am getting my data from firebase and putting them into the recyclerview to display a list of products.

I would be really great if you can point out what is wrong with my code so that i can correct it.

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `startListening()` to start listening for data in [firebaseui](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md):

> The FirebaseRecyclerAdapter uses an event listener to monitor changes to the Firebase query. To begin listening for data, call the startListening() method. You may want to call this in your onStart() method. Make sure you have finished any authentication necessary to read the data before calling startListening() or your query will fail.

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    firebaseRecyclerAdapter.startListening();
}
```